# Create a valueBox with deltas in Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

I'd like to create a dashboard in R shiny with deltas in `valueBox` like shown in the picture.
How can I do that?

**Boxes with deltas**

[image: Boxes with deltas]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use colored icons like this https://www.flaticon.com/free-icons/triangle or https://fontawesome.com/v5.15/icons/caret-up?style=solid?

Comment: You should make your question more specific. Probably you want to know whether there are existing add-on packages to shiny that offer a value box which also shows deltas, or how one can implement this in shiny or a rather basic package like shinydashboard. For the latter it would be great if you’d provided a minimal example of a dashboard with a valueBox together with a data.frame or vector containing a delta.